# Modules and inlining in C++

Tags: c++, module, inline, c++20

I am curious about one thing when modules go into C++. Before there were header files and .cpp files. .cpp functions cannot be inlined.

Here is my question. Inlining semantics are not going to be changed as far as I know, but, if I implement (not inline) a function:

```
module blabla;

export class MyClass {
public:
  void f();    
};

void MyClass::f() { /*Implementation*/ }
```

Will the optimizer be able to inline the function in this case, because the function is still implemented in the same module? Before it was imposssible as far as I know, since it goes into a dedicated implementation file.

Comment: *".cpp functions cannot be inlined."* That's not true, LTO does that.

Comment: IMO, in a header, function can be inlined by compiler yes

Comment: @BaummitAugen ok. I did not know that. Thanks for the information. Anyway, activating LTO in large programs... you know... :D

Comment: @GermánDiago: large projects can use LTO (and PGO) for their final builds -- and if you need LTO day to day, take a look into ThinLTO.